# Problems when importing font into SketchUp

Tags: font-management, sketchup

I am trying to make 3d text in Sketchup but the font I want is not showing up. The font (Gotham) is loaded on my computer and I am able to use it in Photoshop, Word, etc but can't find it in Sketchup. I think it is a purchased font. Does anyone have any ideas why this font isn't showing up and how I can load it into sketchup?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Fonts for SketchUp layout need to be either True Type (TTF) or Open Type (OTF), but it seems that **for 3D text SketchUp only supports TTF** (and not OTF).

It seems like the Gotham package is usually sold in OTF, it's something worth checking just in case, but unless you have it in a different format you won't be able to use it for 3D.

I don't think it's legal to convert OTF to a different format, but if you are using it for a personal project or for learning, you can try an online converter like [Free Online Font Converter](http://www.freefontconverter.com/) to export it in TTF.

Comment: One could also type it in Inkscape, for example, then convert to outline, then import that into Sketchup

Answer (score 0):

https://convertio.co/otf-ttf/

This is all you need to do. Convert with this tool.

Comment: Hi Doby, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks for your effort and keep contributing!